# why "repeat" function is cancelable in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
val job = launch {
    repeat(1000) { i ->
        println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
        delay(500L)
    }
}
delay(1300L) // delay a bit
println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
job.cancel() // cancels the job
job.join() // waits for job's completion 
println("main: Now I can quit.")
```

}
this code not check isActive or use suspend function but can canceled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the analogy with Java threads:

1) Checking the interrupted flag explicitly:

```
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    // loop code
}
```

2) Calling interruptible operations:

```
while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(1);
    // loop code
}
```

In both cases the thread will respond to a raised interrupt flag.

In coroutines, `delay()` is the counterpart of `Thread.sleep()` and the `isActive` flag is the counterpart of the `Thread.interrupted` flag.

Therefore, when you write

```
delay(1)
```

the coroutine will be scheduled off the thread and, when its time to resume comes, inside the `continuation.resume()` call it will first check the `isActive` flag. If it's raised, it will throw a `CancellationException` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because `delay()` is a suspend function.

`Thread.sleep()` is not a suspend function.
If you replace `delay(500L)` with `Thread.sleep(500)`, then it will not be cancellable on time.